# Collision of balls with each other

Tags: java, algorithm, swing

I'm working on animation of moving balls, which must collide with walls and with each other.
Half the work is done. Balls already can collide with walls.
But I don't know how to make a collision of balls with each other. I tried using the loop throughout the ArrayList collection, but the balls are removed incorrectly.
Maybe you can help me with this task.

MainClass.java

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class MainClass
{
    public static Timer t; 

    public static void main(String[] args)  
    {

        UI myUI = new UI();
        EventQueue.invokeLater(myUI);

        t = new Timer(10, myUI);
        t.start();
    }

}
```

UI.java.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class UI extends JFrame implements Runnable, ActionListener
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(600, 500);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setTitle("Bouncing Balls!");

        add(new DrawingSurface());
        setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        repaint();
    }


}
```

DrawingSurface.java

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class DrawingSurface extends JPanel
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    static ArrayList<BouncingBall> bList = new ArrayList<BouncingBall>();
    private final int numBalls = 2;
    Random r = new Random();
    int rangeMin = 1, rangeMax = 3;
    double randomXSpeed;
    double randomYSpeed;


    // create a list of balls in the constructor. This way it happens only one time
    // rather than EVERY time you re-draw...
    public DrawingSurface()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < numBalls ; i++)
        {
            randomXSpeed = rangeMin + (rangeMax - rangeMin) * r.nextDouble();
            randomYSpeed = rangeMin + (rangeMax - rangeMin) * r.nextDouble();
            // Notice I delegate ALL of the ball functionality to the BouncingBall class. 
            // I don't want give it anything to create a new ball. 
            // The only place the balls exist is in the ArrayList.
            bList.add(new BouncingBall(r.nextInt(400), r.nextInt(300), randomXSpeed, randomYSpeed));  
        }
    }


    public void paintComponent(Graphics gContext)
    {

        // loop through the array list and tell each ball the size of the window
        // and give it the graphics context so it can draw itself.
        for(int i = 0; i < bList.size(); i++)
        {
            bList.get(i).updatePosition(getWidth(), getHeight(), (Graphics2D)gContext);
        }
    }
}
```

BouncingBall.java

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

// a class that manages the position of randomly colored ball, and draws it.
public class BouncingBall extends JPanel
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public int x,y;
    Double xMove;
    Double yMove;
    public final static int size = 20; //size of the ball
    private Color c;

    public BouncingBall(int width, int height, Double xSpeed, Double ySpeed)
    {
        x = width; //starting position
        y = height; //starting position

        xMove = xSpeed; //starting velocity
        yMove = ySpeed; //starting velocity     

        //pick a random color
        c = new Color((int)(Math.random()*255),(int)(Math.random()*255),(int)(Math.random()*255));
    }

    //pass in the height and width of the current window so we can tell where we should bounce
    public void updatePosition(int width, int height, Graphics2D g)
    {
        //update the position
        y += yMove;
        x += xMove;
        Double xSpeed = 0.0, ySpeed = 0.0;

        //if the ball moves to the right edge of the window, turn around. 
        if(x > width - size)
        {   
            x = width - size;
            xMove *= -1;
            if (xMove > 0) {
                xSpeed = xMove + (Math.random() * (1));
            }
            if (xMove <= 0) {
                xSpeed = xMove - (Math.random() * (1));
            }
            if (yMove > 0) {
                ySpeed = yMove + (Math.random() * (1));
            }
            if (yMove <= 0) {
                ySpeed = yMove - (Math.random() * (1));
            }
            DrawingSurface.bList.add(new BouncingBall(x, y, xSpeed, ySpeed));
            c = new Color((int)(Math.random()*255),(int)(Math.random()*255),(int)(Math.random()*255));
        }

        //if the ball moves to the left edge of the window, turn around.
        if(x < 1)
        {
            x = 1;
            xMove *= -1;
            if (xMove > 0) {
                xSpeed = xMove + (Math.random() * (1));
            }
            if (xMove <= 0) {
                xSpeed = xMove - (Math.random() * (1));
            }
            if (yMove > 0) {
                ySpeed = yMove + (Math.random() * (1));
            }
            if (yMove <= 0) {
                ySpeed = yMove - (Math.random() * (1));
            }
            DrawingSurface.bList.add(new BouncingBall(x, y, xSpeed, ySpeed));
            c = new Color((int)(Math.random()*255),(int)(Math.random()*255),(int)(Math.random()*255));
        }

        //if the ball moves to the bottom of the screen, turn around.
        if(y > height - size )
        {
            y = height - size;
            yMove *= -1;
            if (xMove > 0) {
                xSpeed = xMove + (Math.random() * (1));
            }
            if (xMove <= 0) {
                xSpeed = xMove - (Math.random() * (1));
            }
            if (yMove > 0) {
                ySpeed = yMove + (Math.random() * (1));
            }
            if (yMove <= 0) {
                ySpeed = yMove - (Math.random() * (1));
            }
            DrawingSurface.bList.add(new BouncingBall(x, y, xSpeed, ySpeed));
            c = new Color((int)(Math.random()*255),(int)(Math.random()*255),(int)(Math.random()*255));
        }

        //if the ball moves to the top of the screen, turn around.
        if(y < 1)
        {
            y = 1;
            yMove *= -1;
            if (xMove > 0) {
                xSpeed = xMove + (Math.random() * (1));
            }
            if (xMove <= 0) {
                xSpeed = xMove - (Math.random() * (1));
            }
            if (yMove > 0) {
                ySpeed = yMove + (Math.random() * (1));
            }
            if (yMove <= 0) {
                ySpeed = yMove - (Math.random() * (1));
            }
            DrawingSurface.bList.add(new BouncingBall(x, y, xSpeed, ySpeed));
            c = new Color((int)(Math.random()*255),(int)(Math.random()*255),(int)(Math.random()*255));
        }

        g.setColor(c);
        g.fillOval(x, y, size, size);
    }


}
```

Comment: What is the problem? Describe it clearly.

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: I was trying to use something like this:
https://ideone.com/lBpcI7
But if several balls collide at the same time, it does not work.
Maybe you have some ideas on how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
"It does not work" is not a problem specification.  Your posted code doesn't run anything -- it defines four classes and exits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To detect the collision of each ball with one another, a simple way will be looping through the collection of balls with a pair of nested loops. So each ball will be checked against all other balls for collision:

```
//From your list of balls
ArrayList<BouncingBall> bList = new ArrayList<BouncingBall>();

for(BouncingBall b1 : bList)
    for(BouncingBall b2 : bList)
        if(b1.intersects(b2)){
            //do whatever (such as bouncing off) when the balls collide
            b1.flipDirection();
            b2.flipDirection();              
        }
```

In order to use `intersects()` method, your `BouncingBall` class can extends to `Rectangle` class from Java. Alternatively, if you can't let `BouncingBall` class be extended to another class.

You can let them return the bounds:

```
class BouncingBall{
    public Rectangle getBounds(){
        return new Rectangle(x, y, width ,height);
    }
}
```

Then you will still be able to make use of `intersects()` method:

```
//to check for collision using intersects() method
for(BouncingBall b1 : bList)
    for(BouncingBall b2 : bList)
        if(b1.getBounds().intersects(b2.getBounds())){
            //do whatever (such as bouncing off) when the balls collide
            b1.flipDirection();
            b2.flipDirection();              
        }
```

Using nested loop to detect collision for a simple ball animation like this is sufficient. Unless you are making a game where every frame you need to check the collision for thousands or more entities, then you will need a different collision detection algorithm such as Quad-tree.

I have coded such program using the same algorithm before, and it works perfectly well:

[image]

Comment: Can you help me one more time. Please post source code of your flipDirection() function. Thank you so much.

Comment: You can post another question on flipping direction as that will be another question, I will reply it later. I actually up voted your question which gives you 5 reputation points per up vote. Accepting answers earns you 2 points. Higher reputation will give you more previleges in this site.